# I'm having trouble with react-navigation. Can't pass a param through a nested navigation stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

So, I have pretty much tried every adviced way to pass a param through a nested navigator in react-navigation. I saw the last questions about the same issue, tried the code, didn't help. Saw the documentation, tried, didn't solve it. even chatGPT couldn't help. So now I'm humbly asking you for HELP.

I've tried everything I could, and I still cannot get it.

my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Redirector from '../components/redirector';
import RegisterUserAdress from '../components/registerUserAdress';
import RatingsNavigation from '../components/ratings/ratingNavigation';
import FindCLinic from '../components/findClinic';
import Home from '../components/home';

class Stack extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const appNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Redirector: {
      screen: Redirector,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false, // Aqui você define para false para ocultar o cabeçalho
      },
    },
    RatingsNavigation: RatingsNavigation,
    RegisterUserAdress: RegisterUserAdress,
    FindCLinic: FindCLinic,
    Home: Home,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Redirector',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(appNavigation);

export default Stack;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';


import AuthRedirector from '../components/authRedirector';
import RegisterUser from '../components/registerUser';
import Login from '../components/login';
import appNavigation from './appNavigation';

class Stack extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const authNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AuthRedirector: AuthRedirector,
    Login: Login,
    RegisterUser: RegisterUser,
    appNavigation: {
        screen: appNavigation,
        navigationOptions: {
          headerShown: false, // Aqui você define para false para ocultar o cabeçalho
        },
      },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthRedirector',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(authNavigation);

export default Stack;
```

```
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';

import React from 'react';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const statusBarHeight = StatusBar.currentHeight;

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    objeto: [],
  };

  showAlert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      'Usuário não encontrado',
      'Verifique se os dados informados estão corretos.',
      [
        {
          text: 'Entendi',
        },
      ],
      {
        cancelable: true,
      }
    );

  handleEmailChange = (newText) => {
    this.setState({
      email: newText,
    });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = (newText) => {
    this.setState({
      password: newText,
    });
  };

  login = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('http://10.67.168.145:3000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password,
        }),
      });

      // Ensure the response status is ok before trying to parse JSON
      if (response.ok) {
        let data = await response.json();
        if (data.userId) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('appNavigation', {
            screen: 'Redirector',
            params: { idUser: 1 },
          });
        } else {
          console.log('falhou: No userId found in data', JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        
      } else {
        console.error('Erro na requisição:', response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro na requisição:', error);
    }
  };
    
  render() {



    return (
      <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', width: 350 }}>
          <Text style={styles.titulo}> Login </Text>
          <Text> {this.state.logged ? 'logado' : 'Não logado'} </Text>
        </View>

        <TextInput
          placeholder='Digite um e-mail'
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder='Digite uma senha'
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
        />

        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title='Logar'
            onPress={() => {
            this.login();
          }}
            style={styles.button}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputWrapper: {
    width: windowWidth,
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: windowHeight - statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  titulo: {
    fontSize: 35,
    color: '#0c164e',
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    width: 350,
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    paddingBottom: 6,
    marginTop: 35,
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 70,
  },
});

const individualStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  confirmInput: {
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
});
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class Redirector extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
  };  

  componentDidMount() {
    const { route } = this.props;
    console.log(route);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Your TouchableOpacity components here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#0c164e',
    width: windowWidth,
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: windowHeight,
  },
  button: {
    width: 300,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withNavigation(Redirector);
```

Comment: You didn't give any error code, also your code not completed to know what exact issue you're facing, at least show the error, and include minimal code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score -1):

Passing Params in Nested Navigators:

- Using route.params:
  In React Navigation v5 or v6, you can pass params while navigating between screens. Ensure you're passing the params correctly.
- Accessing Params in Nested Stack:
  Make sure you're accessing the params in the correct screen component of the nested stack using route.params.
  Example Code:

Suppose you have a nested stack navigator like this:

```
// Parent Navigator
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="NestedStack"
    component={NestedStackScreen}
    initialParams={{ paramKey: paramValue }} // Initial params for nested stack
  />
</Stack.Navigator>

// Nested Stack Navigator
<NestedStack.Navigator>
  <NestedStack.Screen
    name="NestedScreen"
    component={NestedScreen}
    options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.title })}
  />
</NestedStack.Navigator>
```

- Access route.params in the NestedScreen component:

  function NestedScreen({ route }) {
  const { paramKey } = route.params; // Accessing the parameter here
  // Use the paramKey value in your component
  }
- Troubleshooting Tips:
  Ensure you're passing params correctly when navigating:

  `navigation.navigate('NestedStack', { paramKey: paramValue })`;

  Check the specific version of react-navigation you're using as APIs might differ between versions.
  Verify that you're accessing the correct route.params object in the nested screen component.